# EKS subdomain for each namespac?

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have the following setup. Where I manually add new DNS records when adding new services.

```
       Route53   ------> AWS ALB  -----> Ingress-Nginx in EKS ---> Ingress-Rules -------> Service
(app|api).ex.de | A record target | Target group of listener | Pointing to service
```

Now I want to “duplicate” my environment using namespaces. To do that, I need subdomains and automatic wiring of domains. So for example, I want to have

- dev-namespace -> (app|api).**dev**.ex.de and
- pr-1-namespace -> (app|api).**pr-1**.ex.de

The twist is, that the domains should be automatically wired and setup when I spin up a new environment.

Has anyone an idea how to do this in Kubernetes and AWS? Any help would be appreciated.